# Ruby and Resque Concurrency

Tags: ruby, resque

I am trying to understand how resque is designed and works. I know that it stores JSON objects in Redis, but Redis is just a very fast key-value database. What does that have to do anything with concurrency? Does resque simply create other system processes? How? 'fork' is not supported on Windows. Does it just spawn threads?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, resque forks child processes. I don't know whether it works in windows or not.

Comment: You mean like system processes?

Comment: Yes, processes in the OS terms

Answer (score 2):

Resque basically spawns/copies your rails environments and runs in a new process.

It then uses redis to look for jobs to do in the queue you configured. 
It evaluates the object (that answers the "perform" message) that was found in the queue  with the given arguments.

Comment: What if I am using resque outside of rails ? Is that possible? Will it spawn ruby processes instead? And how does it fork on windows? O_o

Comment: Yes, you can run it outside of rails. I'm not sure how it works on Windows. Yes, you are right, it is memory expensive. You would usually run Resque on a separate machine, dedicated for Resque jobs. Another different approach, that is faster and less memory intensive is Sidekiq. You might wanna try it out: http://sidekiq.org/

Comment: Of course, you might enqueue Resque jobs from a batch script that digests a large file, or from a sinatra app.  Resque workers themselves are spawned via a rake task.